# Construct form-data with duplicate keys in Nodejs client post request body

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data

I am trying to make a post request which body consists of form-data. But the API rest spec, says the form data should look like this :

> names[]= company name 1&names[]=company name 2

I tried

```
    form: {'names[]': "google" ,'names[]': "kraft",  'fields[]': "Country", 
        'fields[]':"ISIN"}
```

But the server receives only the first `names[]` and `fields[]`. The second ones are cut.

> Server:  Post data: {"names"=>["kraft"], "fields"=>["ISIN"]}

Then I tried to add array as value:

```
form: {'names[]': ["google", "kraft"], 'fields[]': ["Country","ISIN"] }
```

> Server: Post data: {"names"=>[{"0"=>"google", "1"=>"kraft"}], "fields"=>[{"0"=>"Country", "1"=>"ISIN"}]}

Looking at the server request, I see that it accepts body in this format:

`BODY: names[]=google&names[]=kraft&fields[]=ISIN&fields[]=Country`

But I cant construct such form in my node-client side.

I am using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

********* **EDIT** ********

This one actually woked:
`form: "names[]=google&names[]=kraft&fields[]=Country&fields[]=ISIN"`

Now the question is how to form this string using https://github.com/form-data/form-data

No append doesn't work I tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended for keys to be unique and not have brackets in their naming. In your case, names[] and fields[] repeat themselves

```
const form = {
    form: {
        names: ['google', 'kraft'],
        fields: ['Country', 'ISIN']
    }
};

request.post('http://yourwebsite.com', form);
```

**EDIT**

```
names[]=google&names[]=kraft&fields[]=ISIN&fields[]=Country
```

May be valid, but depending on framework/language, only one entry will be taken into consideration (first or last). So it is equivalent to

```
names[]=google&fields[]=ISIN // considering first are chosen
```

Also as you can see

> Server: Post data: {"names"=>["kraft"], "fields"=>["ISIN"]}

The brackets were filtered out, so this will be again the same thing

```
names=google&fields=ISIN // considering first are chosen
```

Comment: For some reason doesnt work. A valid form data request  looks like this on the server `BODY: names[]=google&names[]=kraft&fields[]=ISIN&fields[]=Country
`

Comment: Cant I just append the raw form string?

Comment: ONG: this actaully worked `form: "names[]=google&names[]=kraft&fields[]=Country&fields[]=ISIN"` I will construct the form string myself